# Error Inserting data to mysql server through mysqldb in python

Tags: python, sql, mysql-python

MYsqldb is returning 1L when executing this:-

```
db=MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','12345678','kitkat')
cur=db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO justdial(id,email_raw,status) VALUES (NULL,'none','none')")
```

Comment: returning WHERE? on the connect line? on the execute line?

Comment: And why do you think that is an error?

Comment: Because data is not getting inserted into db

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting no errors
Try adding db.commit after your execute

I personally prefer mysql.connector.